# @NgModule static forRoot when implementing dynamic modules

Tags: angular, dynamic, module

I have this code in @NgModule:

```
@NgModule({
 declarations: [
   AppComponent,
   DashboardComponent
 ],
 imports: [
   BrowserModule,
   BrowserAnimationsModule,
   ClarityModule,
   RouterModule.forRoot([
     {
       path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full'
     },
     {
       path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent
     },
   ], {useHash: true}),
   LibraryTestModule.forRoot(ServicetestService),
   HttpModule
 ],
```

If you can see i am injecting the ServicetestService to the LibraryTestModule.

But in my case i am loading this module dynamically using system.js using the code below:

```
// now, import the new module
    return SystemJS.import(`${url}`).then((module) => {
        console.log(module);

        return SystemJS.import(`${url}`).then((module) => {
            console.log(module);
            return this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(module[`${moduleInfo.moduleName}`]).then(compiled => {
                console.log(compiled);
                return module;
            });
        });
    });
```

Now is there any way to inject the ServiceTestService inside the **compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync** method when loading the modules dynamically ??

Comment: `compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync`'s return type seems to be [`Promise<ModuleWithComponentFactories>`](https://angular.io/api/core/ModuleWithComponentFactories).  a `ModuleWithComponentFactories` instance has an [`ngModuleFactory`](https://angular.io/api/core/NgModuleFactory), which has a method `create`. There you can pass an injector, so I think you could add your dependency there.
I'll try it myself this evening or tomorrow.

Comment: Oh okay. Can you please post the code here so i can reproduce it ? I am all new to this dynamically loading modules

Comment: Sure. Please note that I'm not 100% sure this would work. I saw this awesome [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pERhnBBae2k) today which seems to cover a part of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

After exploring a while, I think I've arrived at a solution.

#### widget.module.ts

```js
export const DYNAMIC_CONFIG = new InjectionToken('DYNAMIC_CONFIG');

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
  ],
  declarations: [WidgetComponent],
  entryComponents: [WidgetComponent]

  providers: [
  ]
})
export class WidgetModule { }
```

And now let's presume that you're dynamically loading this module into a shell component:

#### shell.component.ts

```js
ngOnInit () {
    const parentInjector = Injector.create({
        providers: [
            { provide: DYNAMIC_CONFIG, useValue: { message: 'CUSTOM VALUE PROVIDED BY THE CONSUME!' } }
        ],
        parent: this.inj
    });

    import('./widget/widget.module.ts')
        .then(m => {
            this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(m.WidgetModule)
                .then(moduleWithCompFactories => {
                    const module = moduleWithCompFactories.ngModuleFactory.create(parentInjector);

                    /**
                     * Adding the components from the lazy-loaded module
                     * into the current view
                     */
                    this.vc.createComponent(moduleWithCompFactories.componentFactories[0], 0, parentInjector);
                })
        })

}
```

#### shell.component.html

```html
<ng-container #vc></ng-container>
```

As you can see,  if your **dependency**(which is **provided by** the **consumer** of the **module**) will be used **across** your **components** that are part of that module and you use the `compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync` method, the components won't be able to access that dependency, unless another injector is manually created.

This is because, as you can tell by the name of the method, the components will already be compiled, so you can't add another dependencies on the fly, besides those defined **explicitly** in the module.

---

If the components inside the module depend on the provided dependency, you can achieve that by only compiling the module first(`compileModuleAsync`) and then compile each component, individually(it might sound tedious, but I can assure you that you will enjoy working with this stuff). This way, they will be able to inject any dynamically provided dependency, event at runtime.

#### widget.module.ts

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    // RouterModule.forChild([{ path: '', component: WidgetComponent }])
  ],
  declarations: [WidgetComponent],

  // No need to use this when using `compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync`
  entryComponents: [WidgetComponent],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: 'widgets',
      useValue: [
        {
          name: 'widget1',
          component: WidgetComponent,
        },
      ],
    }
  ]
})
export class WidgetModule { }
```

#### shell.component.ts

```js
ngOnInit () {
    const parentInjector = Injector.create({
        providers: [
            { provide: DYNAMIC_CONFIG, useValue: { message: 'CUSTOM VALUE PROVIDED BY THE CONSUME!' } }
        ],
        parent: this.inj
    });

    import('./widget/widget.module.ts')
        .then(m => {
            this.compiler.compileModuleAsync(m.WidgetModule)
                .then(factory => {
                    const module = factory.create(parentInjector);

                    const [firstWidget] = module.injector.get('widgets');

                    const componentFactory = module.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(firstWidget.component);

                    this.vc.createComponent(componentFactory);
                });
        })

}
```

Now, every time you want to add another component to your module, make sure to add it to `entryComponents` and to your *component array* so that you can retrieve them using `module.injector.get()`.

[*Here is a StackBlitz* example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/di-tips?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts).

Comment: Oh greatt. I will try this and tell you if it is working as expected or not. Thankss a lot man you are really saving me. I will tell you as soon as i try this today

Comment: It's my pleasure. I will try to find some time later to reproduce the problem. Good luck!

Comment: I have tested this solution. the injector.Create chunk is deprecated from v5 :/

Comment: Which one are you using? It says [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/di/injector.ts#L67-L72) that only one of the 2 methods is deprecated.

Comment: can you please tell me what is the format that i need to use in order to inject the service in a non deprecated way. this one ( const injector = Injector.create({
            providers: [
                YourAwesomeService,
            ]
        })) is deprecated :/

Comment: Hmm, I couldn't explain why. [Here](https://angular.io/api/core/Injector#usage-notes)  are the usage notes. Maybe you need to explicitly declare the provider? Something like this: `Injector.create({ providers: [{ provide: YourAwesomeService, useClass: YourAwesomeService }] })`

Comment: It did not solve the issue :/ i am getting the undefined metadata error

Comment: Hmm.. I'll take a closer look. Could you add the error in your post?

Comment: this is the error that i am getting. Uncaught (in promise): Error: No NgModule metadata found for 'undefined'.
Error: No NgModule metadata found for 'undefined'.   it is being thrown when i load the module

Comment: I am stuck here in this second thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58709713/ngmodule-loading-dynamic-components-on-runtime-using-systemjs

Comment: Hello Andrei thankss a lot for helping. Are you available for chat ? I need some help

Comment: Hi! I'm having a lot of my plate this week and I can't talk right now, but if you want you can send me a DM with the problem and I'll have a look when I find some time.