# @NgModule loading dynamic components on runtime using SystemJs

Tags: angular, module, systemjs

I am trying to load dynamic components on run time using the compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync function.
while loading the components i am trying to inject a service called **ServicetestService**.

Now what is happening is that when the code reaches :

### Heading ##const cmp = factory.create(inj, [], null, moduleRef);

I am getting this error:

### "Error: StaticInjectorError(ServicetestService)[AnimationBuilder -> RendererFactory2]: \n NullInjectorError: No provider for RendererFactory2!\n at NullInjector.get

Here is the code i am using:

```
return SystemJS.import(`${url}`).then((module) => {
        return this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(module[`${moduleInfo.moduleName}`]).then(moduleWithCompFactories => {              
            const inj = Injector.create(
                {
                    providers: [
                        {
                            provide: ServicetestService, 
                            deps: []
                        }
                    ],  
                    //parent: null,  
                    name: 'ServicetestService' 
                });
            const moduleRef = moduleWithCompFactories.ngModuleFactory.create(inj);
            if(moduleInfo.moduleName === 'LibrarytestModule'){

                //return moduleRef;
                console.log("module:");
                console.log(module);

                console.log("moduleref");
                console.log(moduleRef);

                console.log("factory");
                const factory = moduleWithCompFactories.componentFactories[1];
                console.log(factory);

                console.log("cmp");
                const cmp = factory.create(inj, [], null, moduleRef);
                cmp.instance.ServicetestService = ServicetestService;

                console.log(cmp);
            }
            return module;;
        });
    });
```

this is the syntax of the service i am trying to inject:

```
import { AbstractServicetestService } from 'abstractclasses';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ServicetestService extends AbstractServicetestService{

constructor() {
   super();
}

printhello(){
   alert("Hello from service elie");
}
```

Comment: If you use ‘providedIn: ‘root’’, then you don’t have create another provider for your dependency. Try to remove the Injector.create() part

Comment: When i remove the Injector create part i am getting this Error while loading the module: Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[ServicetestService]:

Comment: Because the module that is being loaded dynamically is expecting a ServicetestService to be injected

Comment: Oh, I see now.. ok. I’ll try to reproduce the problem later in the evening

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I'll be able provide a solution right now. I've seen that [NgModuleFactoryLoader](https://angular.io/api/core/NgModuleFactoryLoader) is now deprecated. I will keep on searching for  a solution though.