# Dynamic tab with lazy load module in Angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to achieve multi tab like this link. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-tabs
But i am trying to achieve with lazy load modules.
How to achieve it?

Comment: You might find this useful: https://juristr.com/blog/2019/10/lazyload-module-ivy-viewengine/
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58695820/ngmodule-static-forroot-when-implementing-dynamic-modules/58696660#58696660) is a SO thread that makes use of that technique.

Comment: thanks,but dynamic import not working.i am using module": "es2015" in my tsconfig.json.if i need to use esNext in module,is need to change angular 7 to angular 8?or can i use esNext with angular7. currently i am using angular 7.

Comment: The above article should work for angular 8 100%

Comment: now component load successfully.but in my case i need to pass a template for open new tab.so i need that component inside template.  like  
<ng-template let-person="viewquot" #viewquot>
    <app-view-quotation></app-view-quotation>
</ng-template>
how can i acheive it?

Comment: I suppose you will pass that `ng-template` to an `ng-container`, right? If so, you wouldn't need a `ng-template`. You can query for the `ng-container` and then, by using the [ViewContainerRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewContainerRef) API, you can attach that component to the `ng-container`: `ViewContainerRef.createComponent(compFactory)`

Comment: Hi  @Andrei Gătej,i was achieved dynamic tab with lazy lode module,the link you gave very useful to me.i used that link in my developing part.Thank you

Comment: Glad it helped!